# Android Video player With in Small layout

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am trying to create an Android video player, similar to the Youtube player. I am going to follow these steps to create the player:

1. Top layout for designing.
2. Middle Layout for VideoPlayer(surfaceView).
3. Bottom layout for Progressbar (Hint: All layout are crated Dynamically)

This is the template of my requirement.

The issue I am facing is that the `SurfaceView` is taking the full length of the display. It is hiding the Top and Bottom Layouts.

What can I do to make to the top and bottom layouts appear ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I dynamically position a surface view. Perhaps someone with more UI knowledge would do something different ... which I'd like to see.

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create objects.
            try {
                mCamera = Camera.open();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("onCreate", "could not open camera", e);
            }
            mLiveGraphView = new LiveGraphView(this);
            mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

            // Create RelativeLayout for layout root.
            mLayoutRoot = new RelativeLayout(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            // Add GraphView to layout.
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpGraph = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            mLiveGraphView.setLayoutParams(lpGraph);
            mLayoutRoot.addView(mLiveGraphView);

            // Add SurfaceView to layout.
            List<Camera.Size> ls = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            int n = ls.size();
            int widthMin = 10000;
            int imin = -1;
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "supported preview width x height: " + ls.get(i).width + " x " + ls.get(i).height);
                if (widthMin > ls.get(i).width) {
                    widthMin = ls.get(i).width;
                    mCameraPreviewSize = ls.get(i);
                    imin = i;
                }
            }
            if (imin >= 0) {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                parameters.setPreviewSize(mCameraPreviewSize.width, mCameraPreviewSize.height);
                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);
                parameters.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_DAYLIGHT);
                parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_SPORTS);
                parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpSurface = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ls.get(imin).width, ls.get(imin).height);
                lpSurface.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                lpSurface.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                mCameraPreview.setLayoutParams(lpSurface);
                mLayoutRoot.addView(mCameraPreview);
            }

            // Provide Android framework with layout root.
            setContentView(mLayoutRoot, rlp);
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403616/layout-aligning-issue-in-android-layout   Please prefer my code in the updated question - i pasted the code over there..

Answer (score 0):

What are you using as the parent layout?  Should either of the top and bottom views be overlaid on top of the VideoView (this is what YouTube does) ?

Here is a sample layout using RelativeLayout that show's this approach:  (Note: position of ViewGroups is important, it decides which views are "on top" vs "below".  ViewGroups closer to the bottom of the file are higher "on top")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the top container!" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the bottom container!" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you do not want the top and bottom views overlaid, you could use a LinearLayout (w/vertical orientation and appropriate layout_heights):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the top container!" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the bottom container!" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403616/layout-aligning-issue-in-android-layout   PLease prefer this link.. i updated the code over there..